# How to put hyperlink on same line?

Tags: html

I was just wondering how to put a hyperlink after the text:

If you require any further information on PCSE, please visit the FAQ section of the PCSE website.- (HYPERLINK HERE)

```
<div class="panel-body">
<p>If you require any further information on PCSE, please visit the FAQ section of the PCSE website.-</p> <a href="http://pcse.england.nhs.uk/help/"></a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you tagged it as C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ending the `<p>` and then adding the `<a>`. If you include the `<a>` in the `<p>`, it should be fine.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<p>If you require any further information on PCSE, please visit the FAQ section of the PCSE website.- <a href="http://pcse.england.nhs.uk/help/"></a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: hyperlink dont appear on view

Comment: @Sam Because you have not writen anything between <a></a> tags. Put the world that you want it to be clickable ad will send you to the url between these tags. Example: <a href="pcse.england.nhs.uk/help/">Click here</a>

Answer (score 0):

Well, if div was big enought, it shouldnt break from starts.

Next, dont use "-". Dash character is used to break the line
Instear, use a non breaking char :  ‑

Comment: true! +ChrisBint --> the <p></p>  is breaking it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<a></a>` tag inside the `<p>...</p>` tag.
In your case the solution would look like:

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <p>
         If you require any further information on PCSE, please visit the FAQ section of the PCSE website.- <a href="http://pcse.england.nhs.uk/help/"></a>
     </p>
</div>
```

Comment: the hyperlink dont appear

Comment: @Sam Because you have not writen anything between <a></a> tags.
Put the world that you want it to be clickable ad will send you to the url between these tags. 
Example: <a href="http://pcse.england.nhs.uk/help/">Click here</a>